# Parse the body of request with custom verb Golang

Tags: http, go

I'm so new to Golang and want to create API using `http` package. So I tried the snippet code below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type server struct{}


func (s *server) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)

    r.ParseForm()
    fmt.Println(r.Header["Content-Type"][0])
    fmt.Printf("The URL is: %s\n", r.Form)
}

func main() {
    s := &server{}

    http.Handle("/", s)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

The request is:

```sh
curl localhost:8080 -d url=google.com -i
```

And the output:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
The URL is: map[url:[google.com]]
```

Everything is ok till using the custom verb like:

```sh
curl localhost:8080 -d url=google.com -i -X CREATE
```

And the output:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
The URL is: map[]
```

There is an issue with `http` package and HTTP custom verbs?

Or something wrong in my code?

Comment: there is an industry convention to avoid creating arbitrary http verbs ... checkout https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/193821/are-there-any-problems-with-implementing-custom-http-methods   to quote from RFC 1925 http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1925.html    - "In protocol design, perfection has been reached not when there is nothing left to add, but when there is nothing left to take away."

Comment: "There is an issue with http package and HTTP custom verbs?" Package net/http deals with HTTP, not some self-invented abomination of HTTP so that is to be expected.

Comment: @Volker There are various web services using custom methods and there is no restriction on not using custom methods. But I expected raised error, not ignoring the form parameters implicitly.

Comment: Not sure where you're expecting an error to be raised, as you're not checking any of your errors.

Comment: @Adrian As I said, I'm new to Golang. So I forgot for a  moment that error handling in Golang is different from other languages like Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request

> Form contains the parsed form data, including both the URL field's query parameters and the PATCH, POST, or PUT form data.
>   This field is only available after ParseForm is called.
>   The HTTP client ignores Form and uses Body instead.

And if we look at [the code](https://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go?s=40015:40270#L1228) for `ParseForm` we see:

```
if r.PostForm == nil {
    if r.Method == "POST" || r.Method == "PUT" || r.Method == "PATCH" {
        r.PostForm, err = parsePostForm(r)
    }
    if r.PostForm == nil {
        r.PostForm = make(url.Values)
    }
}
```

The easy way to do it would be to make it think it's a POST request (and then set it back afterwards, in case you need the real method later):

```
  method := r.Method
  r.PostForm == nil // this line may necessary
  r.Method = http.MethodPost
  r.ParseForm()
  r.Method = method
```

Comment: This works but it seems like a hack. Isn't there any official way to do that? Like any method? I wonder why `ParseForm` doesn't support custom verbs.

Comment: No, if there was an "official way" the workaround wouldn't be necessary. If you have concerns about the `net/http` implementation, take it up with the maintainers (e.g. on the golang-nuts mailing list).

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in `ParseForm`'s source in `net/http/request.go`

```golang
        if r.Method == "POST" || r.Method == "PUT" || r.Method == "PATCH" {
            r.PostForm, err = parsePostForm(r)
        }
```

It will only parse a POST body if method is either POST, PUT or PATCH.

You can force this by adding `r.Method = "POST"` before calling `r.ParseForm`:

```golang
    r.Method = "POST"
    r.ParseForm()
```